# Basic Web Service Scala + JEE6 + weblogic

Tags: java, scala, weblogic-10.x

I am trying to write a basic web-service is scala using JEE6 libraries and want to deploy it on weblogic server 10.3

I followed the procedure mentioned in the following link :

the first discussion in http://www.dzone.com/links/search.html?query=scala+ws&x=0&y=0

It's done up to the packaging step. Can anyone help me to deploy it on wls10.3?

I am using Ubuntu 12.04.

While deploying through weblogic console I am gettin the following error:

*NoClassDefFoundError :  scala/ScalaObject*

Thanks in advance,

Arpan

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will need to package your .war file with the Scala libraries (`scala-library.jar`). See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3026911/packaging-and-deploying-scala-applications) for more info re doing this with SBT.